# How to make the row names and column names into factor or one of the fields in R?

Tags: r

How can I turn the following matrix (or table/data frame) with row names & column names,

```
    A       B
M   27143   18324
F   29522   18875
```

into something like

```
27143  M  A
18324  M  B
29522  F  A
18875  F  B
```

so that I can do some analysis in R?

Comment: Please use `dput()` as detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: What is the origin of your data? Is it the result of `table()`, by any chance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `reshape2` package and `melt` the data.

```
temp = read.table(header=TRUE, text="    A       B
M   27143   18324
F   29522   18875")
library(reshape2)
temp$id = rownames(temp)
melt(temp)
# Using id as id variables
# id variable value
# 1  M        A 27143
# 2  F        A 29522
# 3  M        B 18324
# 4  F        B 18875
```

Comment: Thank you for this! exactly what I was looking for. Just out of curiosity, is there a way to revert the process? in other words, "un-melt" it?

Comment: found it! dcast or acast was the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `data.table`to add the row names as first column then you melt it based on their row names

```
df<- structure(list(A = c(27143L, 29522L), B = c(18324L, 18875L)), .Names = c("A", 
"B"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("M", "F"))

library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
setDT(df, keep.rownames = TRUE)[]

#   rn     A     B
#1:  M 27143 18324
#2:  F 29522 18875

(melt(df, id.vars="rn"))
#   rn variable value
#1:  M        A 27143
#2:  F        A 29522
#3:  M        B 18324
#4:  F        B 18875
```

Or use `gather` instead `melt`

```
library(tidyr)
gather(df, "rn")
#  rn rn value
#1  M  A 27143
#2  F  A 29522
#3  M  B 18324
#4  F  B 18875
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the example using `gather`. Can you provide more details? Thanks!